# Agrupamento dos dados - Histograma R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histograma

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou tentando fazer um histograma com o ggplot(), mas estou com muita dificuldade em um detalhe.

Basicamente eu gostaria de  agrupar manualmente os dados que ficam inseridos dentro de cada bin do meu histograma.

```
p8 <- ggplot(TGL_Filtered , aes(x = TP)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..), binwidth = 2.5,
                 colour = barlines, fill = barfill) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Tp (s)",
                     breaks = seq(0, 25, 5),
                     limits=c(0,25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Porcentagem %") +
  ggtitle("Período de Pico") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size=1, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3",linetype = "dashed"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
        text=element_text(family="Tahoma"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(colour="black", size = 9),
        axis.text.y=element_text(colour="black", size = 9))

p8
```

gostaria que as barras ficassem representassem intervalos que eu determino.
EX ao invez de aparecer o número 2, 4, 6 em baixo de uma barra, gostaria que aparecesse [2 a 4), [4 a 6), [6 a 8).e

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Olá Rodrigo Rsilva, quando aplicamos o Histograma ele já vem definido por cálculos estatísticos. A partir da amostra de dados, cálculo de amplitude e análise de classes. O mesmo acontece com o gráfico de boxplot, eles já possuem regras definidas para análises estatísticas e por mais que gostaríamos de mudar, tanto `hist()` quanto `boxplot()` eles já são definidos  da maneira mais ideal para que nos ajude a interpretar os nossos dados.

Comment: Pois é, me parece que é isso mesmo.
por isso que gostaria de configurar eu mesmo o agrupamento dos dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa pergunta não é trivial mas é importante porque nunca tinha aparecido por aqui. O que você quer **exatamente** é fazer um plot controlando você mesmo a largura dos *bins*. O `geom_histogram` tem o parâmetro `barwith`, entretanto esse parâmetro é um valor único e não resolveria o seu problema. No seu caso você deve definir os `breaks` manualmente, alterar a escala x para corresponder a estes breaks e definir o `stat` para `density`.

**SOLUÇÃO**

Como você não forneceu um exemplo reprodutível eu vou utilizar o conjunto de dados `diamonds` que já vem com o `R`:

```
data("diamonds")
breaks = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 1,2,5)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                 color="blue", fill="blue", breaks=breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks) +
  theme_bw()
```

o resultado é esse aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O melhor ajuste para os `breaks` fica por sua conta na hora de criar o histograma.

Comment: Obrigado Flavio.
inseri uma imagem na minha própria pergunta. o objetivo seria chegar neste grafico que inseri. pensei em fazer da seguinte forma.
- inserir uma coluna no dataframe classificando os valores em grupos que eu quero ( 2 a 4s), (4 a 6s).
depois, colocar dentro do aes(). o eixo x = esta coluna.
sabe se tem alguma forma mais simples?

Comment: Tem sim @RodrigoRsilva. Mas do jeito que você perguntou antes não era essa a pergunta. A minha sugestão: altere novamente o texto da sua pergunta para o que estava, aceite a resposta e poste uma nova pergunta sobre isso que eu respondo para você. Assim fica melhor para o SOpt e não fica confusa a resposta.

Comment: E outra coisa @RodrigoRsilva, retire a imagem para colocar na outra pergunta porque a imagem que você colocou é de um gráfico de barras e não de um histograma. Coloque a tag gráfico de barras.

Comment: Muito obrigado.